# Android client app talk to normal multiple thread server using socketChannel

Tags: java, android, sockets, socketchannel

I have a android JAVA application which talk to third party server with normal 
TCP serversocket(multiple threading),
Will it work if I use socketChannel client in the android app? the app used to be using socket client, if it is running normal state, it works ok, anyway, if router or network has QOS control, and the sending bitrate is bigger than actual(I'm trying to detect the actual throughput automatically), even I changed the QOS much higher than the sending bps later, the client socket write will still take 1000+ or 2000+ ms even with 1K or 2K data even after pretty long time, and this caused the performance very bad.

I wondering if socketchannel is a good solution to the client side without changing the server.

Thanks :)